# How to change color of Icon which make from createFromIconfontCN with Ant Design?

Tags: css, reactjs, antd, ant-design-pro, icon-fonts

I want to change color of Icon which make by function **createFromIconfontCN**  of ant-design icons tool, but I can't find the way to customize it.
Is there any way to change its color ?
Here is my code:

```
import { createFromIconfontCN } from '@ant-design/icons';

const IconFont = createFromIconfontCN({
  scriptUrl: '//at.alicdn.com/t/font_1920998_qwtyc6g5q7f.js',
});

ReactDOM.render(
  <div>
    <IconFont type="iconright"></IconFont>
  </div>,
  mountNode,
);
```

You can check it out here:
https://ant.design/components/icon/ 
Section: **Use iconfont.cn**

Thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you include a `style` property with the color you want, it changes the color.

```
<IconFont type="iconright" style={{ color: "green" }} />
```

check [this](https://codesandbox.io/s/black-https-yd803) sandbox